# How to get screen output from a background python program

Tags: python, background-process

I'm running a home heating system monitor on a BeagleBoard xM (arm7) using Ubuntu 16.04.2 and Python 2.7.12. My Python program auto runs on boot via a cron job. The board runs headless. I access it using WinSCP to get my data file and Putty to check on things.

Everything is working fine, but I would like to have my current sensor readings auto print to a screen. I'm not sure how to do this, since my program runs headless in the background.

By screen, I mean either a small hdmi monitor I could attach to the board (in which case it would be in a different session without a keyboard) or a new terminal session I would start via Putty.

So, my question is there a way to get screen output from a background program automatically to a screen in a different terminal session?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you could use [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) to run your python program. Then, at any time that you want to check on it you can reattach to the pid. The way it usually works is:

```
screen -S <name_your_screen>
```

Is not necessary to name the screen but makes it easier to find them later if you run more than one screen. At this point you will be in the screen's interactive shell. Run your python program as your normally would. Later when you want to check on the program via Putty or something:

```
screen -list
screen -r <pid>.<name_of_screen>
```

Another option is [tmux](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E86824_01/html/E54763/tmux-1.html). Hopes this helps.

Comment: Thanks breheme - screen does solve part of what I want to do. Now I need to figure out how to use screen in a cron job, if possible, so that my Python program auto runs on boot. We have power outages here in NH.

Comment: This should work: `@reboot /usr/bin/screen -S <screen-name> -d -m /path/to/python/program.py` make sure to use full paths. I think it gets angry if you don't.